# Can't build Xamarin android app - proguard error

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a problem to build xamarin mobile app. It stopped working and I don't know how to solve it. I tried to reinstall visual studio and android studio too. The file proguard.txt is present in the path on the disk. I use visual studio 2019. Please help me how to solve it. [image: These are errors after build.]

Comment: VS for Mac or Windows? Also how you tried to change your project settings so that there is no code shrinking for the particular configuration you are trying to build? Does it build then? Also what happens if you toggle the "Linker Behavior" setting?

Comment: @d_pawe, you use proguard in your android project? If yes, I suggest you can take a look the [ProGuard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/proguard?tabs=windows) firstly, to check configuration.

Comment: @Saamer, VS for Windows. I think that the code does build.

Comment: @Cherry Bu - MSFT, I don't use proguard there.

Comment: The build fails on nuget package Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration (1.0.0-preview06) with the error which is on the screenshot.

Comment: @d_pawe, Can you provide one simple sample that can reproduce this issue here, because it is difficult to find one solution according to error message.